# How to sort a specified column in l、Linux

Tags: bash

This is my two column sequence, I want to combine them into 1 column and sort them in Linux, but I don't know how to write the shell script to handle them.

```
    GGCTGCAGCTAACAGGTGA         TACTCGGGGAGCTGCGG
    CCTCTGGCTCGCAGGTCATGGC      CAGCGTCTTGCGCTCCT
    GCTGCAGCTACATGGTGTCG        CGCTCCGCTTCTCTCTACG
```

The sorted results are as follows (first column first, second column second, and split by "\t")

```
1 GGCTGCAGCTAACAGGTGA         
2 CCTCTGGCTCGCAGGTCATGGC      
3 GCTGCAGCTACATGGTGTCG        
4 TACTCGGGGAGCTGCGG
5 CAGCGTCTTGCGCTCCT
6 CGCTCCGCTTCTCTCTACG
```

what should I do？

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily in `awk` by storing the second column in an array and then outputting the saved values in the `END` rule, e.g.

```sh
awk '
  {
    print ++n, $1       # output first column
    a[n] = $2           # save second column in array
  } 
  END {
    j = n + 1           # j is next counter
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)  # loop 1 - n
      print j++, a[i]   # output j and array value
  }
' file.txt
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your input in `file.txt`, you can just copy/middle-mouse-paste the above in an xterm with `file.txt` in the current directory, e.g.

```
$ awk '
>   {
>     print ++n, $1       # output first column
>     a[n] = $2           # save second column in array
>   }
>   END {
>     j = n + 1           # j is next counter
>     for (i=1;i<=n;i++)  # loop 1 - n
>       print j++, a[i]   # output j and array value
>   }
> ' file.txt
1 GGCTGCAGCTAACAGGTGA
2 CCTCTGGCTCGCAGGTCATGGC
3 GCTGCAGCTACATGGTGTCG
4 TACTCGGGGAGCTGCGG
5 CAGCGTCTTGCGCTCCT
6 CGCTCCGCTTCTCTCTACG
```

Or as a 1-liner:

```
$ awk '{print ++n, $1; a[n]=$2} END {j=n+1; for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print j++, a[i]}' file.txt
1 GGCTGCAGCTAACAGGTGA
2 CCTCTGGCTCGCAGGTCATGGC
3 GCTGCAGCTACATGGTGTCG
4 TACTCGGGGAGCTGCGG
5 CAGCGTCTTGCGCTCCT
6 CGCTCCGCTTCTCTCTACG
```

If you would like to create an `awk` script from the above, you can simply create the script file (say `cmbcols.awk`) as:

```
{
  print ++n, $1       # output first column
  a[n] = $2           # save second column in array
}
END {
  j = n + 1           # j is next counter
  for (i=1;i<=n;i++)  # loop 1 - n
    print j++, a[i]   # output j and array value
}
```

Then to run the script on the file `file.txt` you can do:

```
$ awk -f cmbcols.awk file.txt
1 GGCTGCAGCTAACAGGTGA
2 CCTCTGGCTCGCAGGTCATGGC
3 GCTGCAGCTACATGGTGTCG
4 TACTCGGGGAGCTGCGG
5 CAGCGTCTTGCGCTCCT
6 CGCTCCGCTTCTCTCTACG
```

Comment: Thank you @ David C. Rankin for your solution, it was really helped!

Comment: @Daffy - glad to help. Good luck with your scripting. `awk` is one of the most flexible text manipulation utilities ever made. Any time you spend learning `awk` is time well spent.